# CreateRemoteThread, doesn't start a thread

Tags: c, winapi

I use this function as usual, but the debug traces (OutputDebugString) don't work from injecting dlls. And in the target application no thread is created (I look through the process hacker)
GetlastError says 0
CreateRemoteThread says tid
but WaitForSingleObject exits immediately (why if all ok!?)
... I'm confused %
OS windows 10 x64
app and dll - x86

code dll is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE h, DWORD reason, LPVOID res)
{
    CHAR pszMessage[1024] = { 0 };
    sprintf(pszMessage, ("L2Proj: GetCurrentProcessId() %d, hModule 0x%p, nReason %d\r\n"), GetCurrentProcessId(), h, reason);
    OutputDebugString(pszMessage);
    switch(reason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                    //MessageBoxA(NULL, "inject success", "done", MB_OK);
                    TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), -1);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

PS TerminateProcess in dll doesn't work either

PPS GetExitCodeThread() after WaitForSingleObject ends is 0

What it the problem with?

**ADDED**

APP code is:

NOTE: This is just test code (no control over return values ​​/ wrong label name codestyle etc.), pls do not tell me about it.

I wrote step by step in the comments which functions return which values

```
    // process of course has access
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
    // handle is valid
    if(!hProcess) {
        return GetLastError();
    }


    DWORD id;
    char str[] = "G:\\workspace\\proj\\test.dll";
    void *l = (void*)GetProcAddress(
            GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    // addr is valid
    if(!l) {
        return 35;
    }

    DWORD str_size = strlen(str) + 1;

    // memory addr is valid
    LPVOID lp = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, str_size, MEM_COMMIT | 
                                                        MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    BOOL res = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lp, str, str_size, NULL);
    // res is true

    HANDLE h = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess,
            NULL,
            0,
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)l,
            lp,
            0,
            &id);

    // handle is valid
    // id is valid (tid remote thread)
    if(!h) {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    CHAR pszMessage[1024] = { 0 };
    sprintf(pszMessage, ("L2Proj: GetProcessId() %d\r\n"), id);

    OutputDebugString(pszMessage);
    // ends immediately (no waiting)
    WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);

    GetExitCodeThread(h, &id);
            //id is 0 (exit code)

    sprintf(pszMessage, ("L2Proj: GetExitCodeThread() %d (GetLastError=%d)\r\n"), id, err);
    OutputDebugString(pszMessage);

    // the only error after this function (VirtualFreeEx)
    // GetLastError gives 87 (0x57) - ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lp, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    CloseHandle(h);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

I forgot, i use g++ (GCC) 9.3.0 - maybe the problem is because of this?

Comment: problem in you not use debugger

Comment: Please show your code that is injecting the DLL with `CreateRemoteThread()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, just change the compiler.
Yes, the problem was with the compiler, everything works fine on the Microsoft compiler.

Thanks for answers.

> problem in you not use debugger – RbMm yesterday

and yes, I always use the debugger, thanks a lot ...